# Replacing function attribute with variable containing string

Tags: python, django

I want to write code in a singe line to replace the following if-else code.
Can I somehow use the status variable in the filter function directly as an attribute ?

```
status = request_queries.get('status', None)
if status == 'saved':
    queryset = queryset.filter(saved = True)
elif status == 'shortlisted':
    queryset = queryset.filter(shortlisted = True)
elif status == 'accepted':
    queryset = queryset.filter(accepted = True) 
elif status == 'rejected':
    queryset = queryset.filter(rejected = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assume `status` will have as name a valid column name (that is a boolean field), you can use *dictionary unpacking* here:

```
status = request_queries.get('status', None)
queryset = queryset.filter(**{ status: True })
```

You might however want to check if it passes a valid column name, like:

```
status = request_queries.get('status', None)
if status in {'saved', 'shortlisted', 'accepted', 'rejected'}:
    queryset = queryset.filter(**{ status: True })
```

Comment: Getting the following error: "filter() keywords must be strings"

Comment: @user11879807: that's because if `status` is missing in the `request_queries.get('status', None)`, it will return `None`, and hence error. This is *one* of the reasons why you should guard this with a membership check.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a dict with the arguments and use it with `**`:

```
status = request_queries.get('status', None)
kwargs = {status: True}
queryset = queryset.filter(**kwargs)
```